# I'm trying to do a clicker game but it doesn't work, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm really new to python and I'm not trying to do something super special, and I don't know why my clicks counter only counts 1 click and then it doesn't count anymore. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

click = 0
mult1 = 0


def mult():
    global mult1
    mult1 = mult1 + 1


def clicked():
    global click1
    global click2

    click1 = click + 1
    click2 = click1 + mult1

    label1.configure(text=f'Total Clicks: {click2}', font=("Calibri", 26))


def mult():
    global mult1
    mult1 = mult1 + 1


def gui():
    global label1
    global gui

    gui = Tk()
    gui.geometry("800x500")
    btn_click = Button(gui, text="Click to add Clicks!", padx=20, pady=20, font=("Times 16", 15), command=clicked).place(x=310, y=430)
    label1 = Label(gui)
    label1.grid(column=0, row=10)
    gui.mainloop()


gui()
```

Comment: Because `click` always is 0 - you never modify it. So `click1 = click + 1` will always be 1

Comment: What would a fix be?

Comment: click1 = click1 + 1

Comment: `click = click + 1` (or `click += 1`) would update it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you only have one button. `mult` never gets called. `mult1` always stays at 0 because of that. Secondly you use 3 different variables (`click`, `click1` and `click2`) where you only need 1.

```
from tkinter import *

total_clicks = 0
clicks_to_add = 1


def mult():
    global clicks_to_add
    clicks_to_add += 1


def clicked():
    global total_clicks

    total_clicks += clicks_to_add

    label1.configure(text=f'Total Clicks: {total_clicks}', font=("Calibri", 26))

def main():
    global label1
    global gui

    gui = Tk()
    gui.geometry("800x500")
    btn_click = Button(gui, text="Click to add Clicks!", padx=20, pady=20, font=("Times 16", 15), command=clicked).place(x=310, y=430)
    label1 = Label(gui)
    label1.grid(column=0, row=10)
    gui.mainloop()


main()
```